# Setting Color of QPushButton using QColorDialog for undetermined number of buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I am making a RGB program using PyQt5.
This program will get a couple of devices which will have RGB capabilities.
For starters, I will just add one push button per device that when clicked opens up a
color dialog and then sets that button to the color chosen.

Originally, I used a lambda like so:

```
 push_button.clicked.connect(lambda: showColorDialog(push_button))
```

However, I ran into an issue when there was more than one button.
It always sets the color of the last button regardless of which one was pushed.
I saw on another question that lambdas probably caused a scoping issue for this so I switched it to a factory method.
So here is my current code.

```
        self.tab1.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        devices = self.get_devices()
        for device in devices:
            box_layout = QVBoxLayout()
            box_layout.addWidget(QLabel(device))
            push_button = QPushButton("")
            push_button.clicked.connect(self.add_color_dialog(push_button))
            box_layout.addWidget(push_button)
            # Add other stuff here for each device
            self.tab1.layout.addLayout(box_layout)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)
```

```
    def add_color_dialog(self, button):
        def showColorDialog(button):
            color = QColorDialog.getColor()

            if color.isValid():
                color_hex = color.name()

                button.setStyleSheet('background-color: %s' % color_hex)
                logger.info("%s has been set to color: %s" % (button, color_hex))

        return showColorDialog
```

to which I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'setStyleSheet'
```

So at this point I seem to be regressing. I also tried stuffing them all into a button array:

```
self.rgb_buttons = []
... Add button
add method
```

but that also only set the last button oddly. No matter what I try I get an odd error or it sets the last button color instead of the selected button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `push_button.clicked.connect(lambda checked, btn=push_button: self.add_color_dialog(btn))`

Comment: does not work. clicking button does nothing.

Comment: had to edit a bit but that worked, thx. Certainly odd code those